# "Price-is-right" binary search

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I needed to write a function to find what frame of an animation to show given a time point on the animation's timeline. What I ended up writing is what I can only describe as a "price is right" binary search: a binary search that finds the closest value in an ordered list without going over.

For example, if the time is `42`, I want to find the index of the frame to pull up given the following `list` of frame times:

```
times = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 41, 43]   # assumed to be sorted
```

In this case, it would return index `7`, since `41` is the closest time without going over the target time of `42`. My algorithm is below:

```
def binary_search(t, start, end):
    if start == end:
        return start

    if end - start == 1:
        if t < times[end]:
            return start
        else:
            return end

    i = start + ((end - start) / 2)

    if times[i] > t:
        return binary_search(t, start, i)
    elif times[i] < t:
        return binary_search(t, i, end)
    else:
        return i
```

It's not entirely faithful to the price-is-right, because values that are lower than the lowest element can still "win" (eg. `-1` will return index `0`).

So, this all works and is nice. But I'm wondering if this algorithm has a specific name?

[ideone here](http://ideone.com/DLNGX2).

Comment: It is binary search only. FYI, you can always use `bisect` module, where this is pre-implemented.

Comment: Binary system start point is right(not left).
First if you want standard  search need a fixed length or reverse searching with length argument.